# RoR converting a virtual attribute into two database attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, formtastic

I'm currently having trouble finding a nice way to code the following situation:

There is a Model called `TcpService`, which has two attributes, `port_from` and `port_to`, both Integers. It also has a virtual attribute called `portrange`, which is a String. `portrange` is the String representation of the attributes `port_from` and `port_to`, so `portrange = "80 90"` should yield `port_from = 80`, `port_to = 90`. What I'm trying to do now is using the same `Formtastic` form for `creating` AND `updating` a `TcpService`-object. The form looks pretty standard (HAML code):

```
= semantic_form_for @tcp_service do |f|
  = f.inputs do
    = f.input :portrange, as: :string, label: "Portrange"
    -# calls @tcp_service.portrange to determine the shown value

  = f.actions do
    = f.action :submit, label: "Save"
```

The thing is, I don't know of a non-messy way to make the values I want appear in the form. On `new` I want the field to be empty, if `create` failed I want it to show the faulty user input along with an error, else populate `port_from` and `port_to` using `portrange`. On `edit` I want the String representation of `port_from` and `port_to` to appear, if `update` failed I want it to show the faulty user input along with an error, else populate `port_from` and `port_to` using `portrange`.

The Model looks like this, which seems quite messy to me.
Is there a better way of making it achieve what I need?

```
class TcpService < ActiveRecord::Base
  # port_from, port_to: integer
  attr_accessor :portrange

  validate :portrange_to_ports   # populates `port_from` and `port_to` 
                                 # using `portrange` AND adds errors

  # raises exception if conversion fails
  def self.string_to_ports(string)
    ... # do stuff
    return port_from, port_to
  end

  # returns string representation of ports without touching self
  def ports_to_string
    ... # do stuff
    return string_representation
  end

  # is called every time portrange is set, namely during 'create' and 'update'
  def portrange=(val)
    return if val.nil?
    @portrange = val
    begin
      self.port_from, self.port_to = TcpService.string_to_ports(val)
    # catches conversion errors and makes errors of them
    rescue StandardError => e
      self.errors.add(:portrange, e.to_s())
    end
  end

  # is called every time the form is rendered
  def portrange
    # if record is freshly loaded from DB, this is true
    if self.port_from && self.port_to && @portrange.nil?
      self.ports_to_string()
    else
      @portrange
    end
  end

  private
    # calls 'portrange=(val)' in order to add errors during validation
    def portrange_to_ports
      self.portrange = self.portrange
    end

end
```

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your model

```
def portrange
  return "" if self.port_from.nil? || self.port_to.nil?
  "#{self.port_from} #{self.port_to}"
end

def portrange=(str)
  return false unless str.match /^[0-9]{1,5}\ [0-9]{1,5}/
  self.port_from = str.split(" ").first
  self.port_to = str.split(" ").last
  self.portrange
end
```

Using this you should be able tu use the `portrange` setter and getter in your form.

Comment: Sorry for dping, actually I wanted to elaborate a bit, but SO didn't let me edit properly. On trying to create/update, the values disappear in case they were incorrect. That's likely because I call TcpService.new(tcp_service_params). If I feed it `portrange = "X"`, it calls `portrange=("X")`, which returns false, so `port_from` and `port_to` remain unset, resulting in the form to display an empty String instead of the faulty String.

Comment: Yeah of cause they remain unset when you use a faulty format. `return false unless str.match /^[0-9]{1,5}\ [0-9]{1,5}/` is there to verify your using no faulty format. I think I dont really understandwhat you want exactly.

Comment: Sorry then, I meant, that the form is supposed to show the faulty values if validation fails. I used `return @portrange if self.port_from.nil? || self.port_to.nil?` to achieve that and `@portrange = str` in the `portrange=(str)`-method. It's somewhat hard to explain; the actual problem is, that I am using a virtual attribute, so when taking a DB entry, I need to populate that for the form but may not re-use the value taken from the DB later on if validation fails. (On a side note, the max tcp port is 65,535)